# format google sheets charts formatting to filter out certain ranges, emphasize others

Tags: google-sheets, charts

i wanted to ask how do i get google sheets charts to start at a certain value.
I have a chart that i only want to focus on the area between 150 and 160.
unfortunately the chart starts at 0 and takes up too much space of the chart[image]

any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you want format chart axis, you can do it in chart editor:

1. Select chart.
2. Click the three-dot button
3. Click `Edit chart` command.

[image]

Then go to `Customize tab` -> `Vertical axis` -> and enter min and max values

[image]

That's all.